# How to get the compiled query when using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

When using the nuget `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` and its `DocumentClient` class you can get the compiled query that will be executed against cosmos. Like so:

```
var documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey);

var query = documentClient
    .CreateDocumentQuery<Product>(collectionUrl, queryOptions)
    .Where(x => x.Id == "apple-iphone")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Id
    })
    .AsDocumentQuery();

// Here you can inspect the compiled query: "SELECT VALUE {"Id": root["id"]} FROM root WHERE (root["id"] = "apple-iphone")" 
var rawQuery = query.ToString();
```

However when using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`, I dont see any compiled query or how it can be extracted when debugging and inspecting the variables:

```
var container = new CosmosClientBuilder(endpoint, authKey)
    .WithConnectionModeDirect()
    .WithThrottlingRetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 10)
    .Build()
    .GetContainer(databaseId, collectionId);

var query = container
    .GetItemLinqQueryable<Product>(requestOptions: queryOptions)
    .Where(x => x.Id == "apple-iphone")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Id
    })
    .ToFeedIterator();

// How do I get the compiled query here???
var rawQuery = query.ToString();
```

Is there anyway to get the compiled query that will be executed against cosmos when using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you call `ToFeedIterator()`, you can call `queryable.ToQueryDefinition().QueryText` on the `IQueryable`. You can also call `ToString()` directly to get the SQL query definition, just like in v2.